# How can I change the windows icon of several levels in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, icons, favicon

I have got the root window icon displaying fine but how could I set all window icons to be the same?

[image]

I was trying to do this but never worked:

```
levels = ("root_1", "root_2")
for i in levels:
    i.iconbitmap(file_name)
```

Would I have to set each level individually or is there a better way than?

```
root_1.iconbitmap(file_name)
root_2.iconbitmap(file_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem, try this:

```
icons = [file_name_for_root_1, file_name_for_root_2]
levels = (root_1, root_2)
for i in levels:
    i.iconbitmap(icons[i])
```

Comment: Nice, my problem was I had the roots in quotation marks! Now my problem is it is not recognising the other roots/levels(?). Do you know how I could get it to recognise the name for a `tk.Toplevel()` root/level within a function?